# The variables declared in the constructor cannot be accessed by other functions, example is the withdrawrewards function

Tags: solidity

```js
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyToken {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public totalStakedBalance;
    uint256 public rewardRate = 300; // 3%
    uint256 public constant rewardInterval = 72 hours;
    uint256 public constant maxRewardRate = 500; // 5%
    uint256 public constant minStakeAmount = 0.001 ether;
    address[] public stakeHolders;
    address public owner;


    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakeTime;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakedBalance;
    mapping(address => uint256) public rewardBalance;
    mapping(address => uint256) public lastClaimTime;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event Staking(address indexed staker, uint256 value);
    event Unstaking(address indexed unstaker, uint256 value);
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    event RewardClaimed(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event RewardWithdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event EmergencyWithdrawal(address indexed user, uint256 reward);
    event MintAndBurn(uint256 value, uint256 initialTotalSupply, uint256 finalTotalSupply);


   constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _decimals) {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;

        uint256 initialSupply = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;

        // 6000 for circulation
        uint256 circulatingSupply = 6000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = circulatingSupply;

        // 1000 for stake rewards
        uint256 stakeRewards = 1000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += stakeRewards;

        // 1000 for mine rewards
        uint256 mineRewards = 1000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += mineRewards;

        // 4000 for airdrops
        uint256 airdrops = 4000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += airdrops;

        totalSupply = initialSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.sender != address(0), "Invalid sender address");
    require(from != address(0), "Invalid from address");
    require(to != address(0), "Invalid to address");
    require(balanceOf[from] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "Not authorized to spend this amount");
    require(from != to, "Cannot transfer to the same address");

    balanceOf[from] -= value;
    allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;
    balanceOf[to] += value;

    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
}


    function airdrop(address[] memory recipients, uint256[] memory values) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
    require(recipients.length == values.length, "Invalid input arrays");

    uint256 totalValue = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        require(recipients[i] != address(0), "Invalid recipient address");
        totalValue += values[i];
    }

    require(totalValue <= balanceOf[msg.sender], "Insufficient balance for airdrop");

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }

    return true;
}


   function flashMintHook() internal {
        // Perform desired operations here...
    }

    // Flash mint function
    function flashMint(uint256 value) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 initialTotalSupply = totalSupply;
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        require(initialTotalSupply + value >= initialTotalSupply, "Invalid total supply");

        // Mint the tokens
        totalSupply = initialTotalSupply + value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += value;

        // Call the hook function to perform the desired operations
        flashMintHook();

        // Burn the tokens
        uint256 finalTotalSupply = totalSupply;
        totalSupply = initialTotalSupply;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;

        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), value);
        emit MintAndBurn(value, initialTotalSupply, finalTotalSupply);
    }

    function setRewardRate(uint256 _rewardRate) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not authorized");
        require(_rewardRate <= maxRewardRate, "Exceeded maximum reward rate");
        rewardRate = _rewardRate;
    }

    function getStakedAddresses() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return stakeHolders;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _amount) public payable returns (bool success) {
        require(_amount >= minStakeAmount, "Stake amount can't be less than minStakeAmount");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        require(!isStaking[msg.sender], "Already staking");
        require(_amount > 0, "Invalid staking amount");
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] += _amount;
        totalStakedBalance += _amount;
        isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
        stakeHolders.push(msg.sender);
        stakeTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        emit Staking(msg.sender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function unstake(uint256 _amount) public returns (bool success) {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        require(isStaking[msg.sender], "You are not staking");
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient staked balance");
        uint256 stakingPeriod = block.timestamp - stakeTime[msg.sender];
        uint256 reward = (stakedBalance[msg.sender] * rewardRate * stakingPeriod) / (rewardInterval * 100);
        isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        totalStakedBalance -= _amount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount + reward;
        emit Unstaking(msg.sender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function claimReward() public {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        uint256 timeSinceLastClaim = block.timestamp - lastClaimTime[msg.sender];
        uint256 reward = (stakedBalance[msg.sender] * rewardRate * timeSinceLastClaim) / (rewardInterval * 100);
        require(reward > 0, "No rewards available");
        rewardBalance[msg.sender] += reward;
        lastClaimTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
        emit RewardClaimed(msg.sender, reward);
    }

    function withdrawRewards() public {
        require(rewardBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No rewards available");
        uint256 rewardAmount = rewardBalance[msg.sender];
        rewardBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
        stakeRewards -= rewardAmount; // deduct reward from contract balance
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += rewardAmount;
        emit RewardWithdrawn(msg.sender, rewardAmount);
    }


    function emergencyWithdraw() public {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] > 0, "No staked balance");
        uint256 stakedAmount = stakedBalance[msg.sender];
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
        totalStakedBalance -= stakedAmount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += stakedAmount;
        emit EmergencyWithdrawal(msg.sender, stakedAmount);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Invalid address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    function burn(uint256 value) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "Insufficient balance");
        totalSupply -= value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), value);
        return true;
    }

    uint256 constant MINING_INTERVAL = 1 days;
    // Set the maximum number of tokens that can be minted
    uint256 constant MAX_SUPPLY = 1000000;
    // Set the percentage of tokens to be minted at each mining interval
    uint256 constant INFLATION_RATE = 1;
    // Set the time of the last mining for each user
    mapping(address => uint256) lastMiningTime;

    function mine() public returns (bool) {
        
        // Ensure that the user has waited at least MINING_INTERVAL since their last mining
        require(lastMiningTime[msg.sender] + MINING_INTERVAL <= block.timestamp, "You must wait before mining again");

        // Update the last mining time for the user
        lastMiningTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;

        // Calculate the number of tokens to mint based on the inflation rate
        uint256 tokensToMint = (totalSupply * INFLATION_RATE) / 100;

        // Ensure that the total supply does not exceed the maximum supply
        require(totalSupply + tokensToMint <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Maximum supply exceeded");

        // Mint the tokens and update the total supply and the user's balance
        totalSupply += tokensToMint;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += tokensToMint;

        // Emit the transfer event
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokensToMint);

        // Return success
        return true;
    }
    

   mapping(address => uint256) public votes;
    mapping(address => address) public hasVoted;

    function vote(address candidate) public returns (bool success) {
        require(candidate != address(0), "Invalid candidate address");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= 1, "Insufficient balance");
        require(candidate != msg.sender, "You cannot vote for yourself");
        require(hasVoted[msg.sender] != candidate, "You have already voted for this candidate");

        votes[candidate] += 1;
        hasVoted[msg.sender] = candidate;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= 1;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), 1);
        return true;
    }

    function getVoteCount(address candidate) public view returns (uint256 count) {
        require(candidate != address(0), "Invalid candidate address");
        return votes[candidate];
    }

}
```

i am getting an error in the code

Comment: The `stakeRewards uint256` variable is local to the constructor, if you want to access it in other functions you'll have to declare it in the global scope of the contract i.e. outside of the constructor in the constract's storage state.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the question, variables declared in the constructor can't be accessed by other functions. This is because constructor variables are only local to the constructor function and cannot be accessed outside of it, just like variables declared into functions.

If you want to use some of these variables you will have to declare them in the global scope. Then you can use the constructor to initialize them. Something like this:

```
uint256 stakeRewards;
constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _decimals) {
    ...
    stakeRewards = 1000 * (10 ** _decimals);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += stakeRewards;
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I practically figured that out in a hard way after some headache , thank you so much man!